# Winforms globalization issue in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015, globalization

I maintain a WinForms application that I did not write. I used to have Visual Studio 2013 and everything was just dandy. However, an unexpected globalization problem appeared after installing VS 2015. The diacritics have gone rogue.

When in VS designer, I can see proper diacritics:

[image: Proper diacritics when in designer]

However, after compiling and running the application, it goes south:

[image: Wrong diacritics when running the app]

When originally compiling the app in VS 2013, the problem had not occured. Has anyone seen/solved a similar issue?

Comment: Related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31762211/error-string-encoding-windows-10-visual-studio-2015-net-4-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug in VS 2015 that has been fixed and is waiting for a release in toolkit version 1.1:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4022

A neat workaround is to place codepage directly into your .csproj like:

```
...
<PropertyGroup>
    ...
    <CodePage>1250</CodePage>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
...
```

or use a command line build, e.g.:

```
msbuild /p:CodePage=1250;Configuration=Debug
```

Obviously use CodePage that suits your needs. A helpful list is found here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx